# CSS element+element Selector for list item with anchor tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to change the font color of **Country** on hover of list items.
I referred this Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKfma) but in my scenario it is not working . I can't find out where I made a mistake
Here is **my code**

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover + .dropdown>.dropdown-toggle{
    color: yellow!important;
}
```

```html
     <span>
         <li class="dropdown inline">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Country <span class="caret"></span></a>(Color will be changed on hover of countries)
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </span>
```

Comment: I referred this link but in my case its failing buddy

Comment: This is not how `+` works. `A + B` selects a B that comes _immediately after_ A, on the same level. You are trying to do it the other way around, but that is not possible.

Comment: Is there any way to bring the parent color based on child action

Comment: Not actually, that's why I linked the duplicate. But you can perhaps _emulate_ the same effect, if you change the color of Country when the parent LI, `.dropdown`, gets hovered. Assuming your inner list items have full with, therefor cover the same space as the outer LI, hovering over one of the inner LI or the outer is effectively almost the same. Then the only thing left to fix would be that presumable Country should not change color if it itself gets hovered - a rule that explicitly specifies the color for when both the parent LI and Country get hovered would fix that.

Comment: Thank you it was useful to me . Learnt about Css parent selector

Comment: Why do you have a span around your li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below snippet, is this what you want

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
.dropdown:hover  >.dropdown-toggle{
    color: yellow!important;
}
```

```html
<span>
         <li class="dropdown inline">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Country <span class="caret"></span></a>(Color will be changed on hover of countries)
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </span>
```